# Is it possible to control axis number independently of tickSize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

Essentially I want to draw something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEKOg.png (the gridlines, not the graph).

It seems if tickSize is set to one (below) then there are a bunch of lines drawn with their corresponding axis number below them.

```
xaxis, yaxis: {
    show: true,
    min: -20,
    max: 20,
    tickSize: 1,
    tickLength: 0
}
```

If it's not set (below), the graph'll automatically draw one every 5 units along with their numbers

```
xaxis, yaxis: {
    show: true,
    min: -20,
    max: 20,
    tickLength: 0
}
```

I want gridlines every 1 unit but numbers every 5 but I don't see a method to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually specify the tick labels with an array:

```
ticks: [[0, "0"], [1, ""], [2, ""], [3, ""], [4, ""], [5, "5"]],
```

Or, you can specify a function to do it:

```
ticks: function(axis) {
    var tickArray = [[0,"0"]];
    for(var i=axis.min; i<axis.max+1; i++) {
         var label = i%5?"":i;
         tickArray.push([i, label]);
    }
    return tickArray;
},
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/gryozh7x/

You can also use a `tickFormatter`:

```
tickSize: 1,
tickFormatter: function (val, axis) {
    return val%5?"":val;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/gryozh7x/1/

Comment: Can that be placed within a ternary operator? I'm using a grid toggle to a generate and remove a grid for the user. But this won't work:


_opts.xaxes[i].tickFormatter = _opts.xaxes[i].tickFormatter == null ? function (val, axis) {return val%5?"":val;} : null;

Comment: Seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/gryozh7x/2/
Did you remember to redraw the graph/grid, using `setupGrid()` and `draw()`?